# execute os command from python that asks for confirmation

Tags: python, shell

Using python `import os` and `os.system("create-object "+ more-specifications)`, I created a few hundreds of objects, which I now need to delete. I can list the objects created, including their unique `id`.

To delete just one of them, on the command line, I issue

```
delete-object --id cfa2d1417633
```

which will ask for confirmation with

```
Are you sure you want to delete that object (y or n)?>
```

to which I then respont with `y`.

I can generate a list of the id's to delete, but I can't programatically delete them because I don't know how to respond. This, for instance won't work:

```
for objectSpecification in objectList:
    os.system("delete-object --id "+ objectSpecification["id"])
    os.system('n')
```

The delete will not happen and te 'n' causes an error `'n' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You could use popen instead: `p = os.popen(command, "w")` and then `p.write("y\n")`

Comment: Thanks If you post this as an answer, I will accept and upvote it. This would help others with similar problems finding the sollution.

Comment: Maybe `delete-object` accepts a parameter to delete without confirmation, e.g. `delete-object -y OBJECT` or `delete-object -f OBJECT`

Comment: Maybe you can pipe a `y` into it via your shell, e.g. `echo "y" | delete-object OBJECT`

Comment: That probably works, but the solution from user56700 is more flexible, though it is more verbosse

Comment: Unfortinately not, Mark Setchell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to an answer from comment.

Suggestion to a solution, using popen:

```
import os

objectList = []

def deleteObject(objid):
    with os.popen(f"delete-object --id {objid}", "w") as p:
        p.write("y\n")

for objectSpecification in objectList:
    deleteObject(objectSpecification['id'])
```